# How to resize a image of an hyperlink using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to catch an image in hyperlink and resize it for user displaying to end user. Ihave written the following code. But it doesn't help. can you please help me out?

```
if ($(this).find("img").attr("src") != null) {
                    var abc = $(this).attr('id');
                    $("#" + abc).width(20);
                    $("#" + abc).height(20);

                    $("#" + abc).show();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("a").find("img").attr("src", "images/Capture.PNG");

                    }, 6000);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "< a >" tag you are setting dimensions to has display: inline by default. Set display: block to it and your script should work fine.

Comment: I am a bit new to jquery .can you please help me out for writing code.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML source, do not specify width="630". Instead use inline CSS to specify width since jQuery.width() will manipulate CSS width. Also, supply a number without the unit (% or px) to the jQuery.width() function.

**HTML**

```
<a id="viewLarge" class="prepend-7" href="#">View Larger(+)</a>
<img id="newsletter" style="width: 630px" src='http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2475/4008724345_56506c8183_b.jpg'>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#viewLarge").click(function() {
        $("#newsletter").width(950);
    });
});
```

Comment: Than you very much..Monika